# hypothesis test for unpaired data, not normal distribution

Tags: hypothesis-testing, anova, t-test

I have a question as I am currently trying to analyse some data. I have 4 samples of runtime (for each sample n=158, 125, 134, 111 so is unpaired data), each of them giving a mean of 157, 235, 127, 120. I want to see if the highest number 235 is really greater than the rest (hypothesis test). I know I can't use t-test as I have more than 2 samples, and I can't use anova as data is unpaired.
Data is not distributed normally (skewed and weibull distribution for the the 4 samples).

How can I effectively determine if the greatest value of 235 is larger than the rest? What hypothesis test could I use?

Thank you!!!

Comment: What makes you think ANOVA is only for paired data?

Comment: Thank you for your response... I am confuse about aANOVA, as I have only seen examples for paired data, but now you mention... do you think I can use one way ANOVA with the data described before (considering non normal distribution)? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

First, not only does ANOVA not *require* paired data, the usual ANOVA doesn't allow it. If you had paired data, you would have to use something else as the errors would not be independent.

Second, ANOVA does not require that the variables be normally distributed; it assumes that the *errors* are normally distributed. If that is violated (which you can check visually by looking at various plots of the residuals) you could try a robust regression, or, in this case, you might want to transform run time.

Third, I'm a little worried by this:

> I want to see if the highest number 235 is really greater than the
> rest (hypothesis test).

235 is really greater. The hypothesis test would test whether the difference is statistically significant. It answers the question

> If, in the population from which my sample was randomly drawn, the
> null hypothesis was true, how likely is it to get a test statistic at
> least as extreme as the one I got in a sample the size of the one I
> have?

That may be the question you want to ask in this particular case, but often, it is not.